# Call a function in angular which i get as a parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I want to call a function from a string.

That is i am getting a string as the function name but i want to call and execute that function.

I tried the below code but it does not call the method.

```
 linkAction(attr,url){
      if(attr == 'click'){
        debugger
        let eventName = Object.keys(url)[0];
        this[eventName];
      }else{
        window.open(url, "_blank");
      }
    }
```

this code is not calling the method

Comment: Show sample attr and url

Comment: @AdritaSharma Its a string 
So attr can say click or link and url can be www.google.com or a function name like abc()

Comment: why don't you just use `switch case` bcs you already write the function in your component.

Comment: but there are lots of functions so i dont want to do that. I want that string to call the method

Comment: @ashish Have you checked the demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vdjx44?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Try like this:

.html

```
<button (click)="linkAction('click', 'test')">Click me </button>
<button (click)="linkAction('url', 'www.google.com')">Click me url </button>
```

.ts

```
  linkAction(attr, item) {
    if (attr == "click") {
      this[item]();
    } else {
      if (item !== "" && item !== undefined) {
        if (item.includes("http")) {
          window.open(item, "_blank");
        } else {
          window.open(`https://${item}`, "_blank");
        }
      }
    }
  }

  test() {
    alert("test called");
  }
```

Comment: Can you check the demo? the first button.